# DevOps Server 2019.0.1 (Azure DevOps Error - TF30063: You are not authorized to access tfs.)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

After updating from TFS 2018 v3 to DevOps Server 2019.0.1 last weekend I now receive this authentication error when attempting to manage security:

`TF30063: You are not authorized to access tfs.`

I receive this error when attempting to manage security from the Server Administration Console via Application Tier > Administer Security. I also receive the error when I attempt to set permissions via tfssecurity cli tool. I am in the local administrator group and I am listed in the console administration user section.

I'm trying to set permissions because after the update I received several reports from employees that receive errors when they try to access their projects. Those errors are:

`TF40049: You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Code.`

*** Edit: Update

This error reoccurred when I upgraded from 2019 to 2020 RC1. The difference is, this upgrade required a migration of the server- since  server requirements changed for the new version of DevOps Server.

Answer (score 1):

I spent 8 hrs working through this issue yesterday, and this is what fixed our problem:

- deleted DevOps server cache. (location of cache listed in devops admin console on server)
- reboot server.

I deleted the cache off the server based on an article I read with the same error, a user was having security/permissions issues with visual studio and they deleted the vs cache on their local machine and it solved their problem. I don't know if deleting the cache or the reboot would have fixed it independently because I did them both as a single troubleshooting step.

Hope this helps someone.

** Edit: Update 08/13/20 **

After upgrading again, I have ran into the same issue and this does not fix my error anymore. I've tried deleting the server cache, rebooting, reapplying permissions, configuring a new service account, reapplying changes, rebooting again, etc. I still have not found a solution for this error. I cannot schedule backups through the supplied backup scheduler without permissions to manage security settings through the configuration panel.